# how to make a button that share my res/raw/xxx.mp3 file

Tags: android, mp3, share, whatsapp

My  app  use MP3 files with MediaPlayer, i want to make a button than will share an MP3 file to whatsapp.

my code is this:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String audioClipFileName="bell.mp3";
    sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+"/sdcard/"+audioClipFileName));
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

but its not working.why is not working?how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Did you copy the file out to the stated path? If not, what makes you think that it will be there? Also, **never hardcode root paths**. There are many, many devices for which `/sdcard` will not work.

Comment: the path can be  res/raw/xxx.mp3 ?

Comment: Shouldn't your extra files be in assets folder to begin with  ?

Comment: those are files that i use in my project.. not user's files..

Comment: try changing `startActivity(sendIntent)` to `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share sound"));`

Comment: "the path can be res/raw/xxx.mp3" -- that is not a file on the Android device. So, I ask again: did you copy the file out to the stated path? Please show the code where you copied this raw resource out to the path designated by your `Uri.parse()` call.

Comment: @ADAMCOHENHILLEL plz change `"file://"+"/sdcard/"` to `"file:///sdcard/"` there is no need for the **+** for two string types

Comment: i did not copy, how do i copy?or if you suggest a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use Environment and not hardcode path, for example, if your file is in sdcard root use a code like this:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String fname = "bell.mp3";
file = new File(root, fname);

Intent shareCaptionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareCaptionIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOURTEXT");
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.toString()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareCaptionIntent, "Share in:"));
```

If a resource use this:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/raw/" + fname);
```

Or resource ID

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.bell.mp3);
```

Any error please share logcat

Comment: and if my path is res/raw/xxx.mp3?

Comment: @ADAMCOHENHILLEL I update the answer, use Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/raw/" + fname); for resources

Comment: Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  
  String audioClipFileName="bell.mp3";
  sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.gruchka.guessthesound/raw/" + audioClipFileName));
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Get help with:"));

Comment: Or use resource ID, share logcat  Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.bell.mp3);

Comment: How can i add to the audio also text?

Comment: Try using Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/raw/bell"); with .mp3 extension, the posted in answer is the way that I use.

Comment: For text use shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR_TEXT");

Comment: This is what i did but the intent type is audio/mp3 and it is need to be something else